# Installing MySQL and configuring for php

Tags: mysql

I m using Wamp as a server, I want to download My Sql for web connectivity, but dnt kno which is the most reliable tutorial or guide from which i can download mysql. Please guide me. its urgent. Also how to configure or use this with php

Comment: WAMP (Windows Apache/MySQL/PHP) comes with MySQL...

Comment: ok, Thanks, But then how to install the database client, in which i can make databases of my own

Comment: It comes with phpMyAdmin, also...

Answer (score 0):

1,  Go here : http://www.mysql.com/downloads/installer/

2, Press download

3, Follow instructions (next, next, finish,...)

Comment: ok, this is complete version, means database client is also included in this.